# "Failed to load resource" error when displaying data in odp format with ViewerJs

Tags: html, iframe

I wanted to show a slide in odp format using ViewerJs.

I converted a file in Microsoft Office's PowerPoint application from the ".pptx" extension to the ".odp" extension.

I manually replaced "ohm2013.pptx" with "ohm2013.odp" and "ohm2013.ods" and added it to my project.

[Image of the files I added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cCsH.png)

and my code;

```
<iframe src="/ViewerJS/#../ohm2013.pptx" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="/ViewerJS/#../ohm2013.ods" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe src="/ViewerJS/#../ohm2013.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and result;

[html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36V5m.png)

What can I do for the ".odp" extension?

Comment: Look at the path in your console error .. It's giving you a 404 (NOT FOUND).  It is looking for the `/ohm2013.odp` in the "root" directory.--> `https://localhost:44309/ohm2013.odp`  Whereas your code is telling it to look in the `/ViewerJS` directory ..  I can only assume it has to do with the `#..` (as two dots in a row means **back one** or **up one** directory) -- 
 unless you used that as "filler" as to not display your full directory on SO.

Comment: yes its for console said NOT FOUND, but this here. When i try to download;<br>


<a href="~/ViewerJS/test.odp" download="">~/ViewerJS/test.odp</a>
<br>
again not found i dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do this job
webodf requires an http-server for files with odp extensions and this must be run in the path of http server viewerjs.

I did this with the nodejs command prompt like this

`npm install http-server -g`

`http-server "C:\Users\subUser\source\repos\Works\OdpViewerJs\ViewerJS"`

and the result

```
Available on:
   http://192.168.1.8:8081
   http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

and I created test.html for the server I ran above;

```
<html dir = "ltr" lang = "en-US">
     <body>
<iframe src = "/#../test.odp" width = '400' height = '300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen> </iframe>
     </body>
</html>
```

and then just go to "`http://localhost:8081/test.html`"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaqtf.png)